# Что изменить в Аpache, чтобы зайти на сайт с другого компьютера?

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, php

Добрый день.

Может элементарный вопрос. У компа адрес 192.168.1.8,  но работает только localhost или 127.0.0.1.

Что сделать в апаче, чтобы можно было и c самого компьютера по этому адресу зайти и с других компов?

Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман РакзинЮ уточните операционную систему.

Comment: Windows 8 (64)

Answer (score 1):

Могу только предположить, что вы все в одной сети и проблемы с маршрутизацией запросов нет.

В апаче за "прослушку" поступающих запросов отвечает директива Listen

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Поменяйте на

```
Listen 80
```

И рестарт апача.

Comment: Плюс переписать virtual hosts, если они тоже забиты на конкретный айпи.

Answer (score 0):

В файле hosts добавьте ip компьютера, к которому надо подключится.

Comment: У меня сервер с этим ай-пи. А другие не могут подключится. И он сам, кстати, тоже по адресу 192.168.1.8 не заходит.